# Safe conversion from byte code to iso8859-1

Tags: php, character-encoding, byte

my question is if there is a php function which converts a byte code to a specific character encoding. In my case I want to encode from byte code to iso5589-1. So for example "196" in iso5589-1 would be "Ä". So my function should look like this pseudo code:

```php
function getSafeSpecialCharacters($sc) {
    return safeconversion(196, "ISO559-1");
}
```

Since now I found only chr() in php, but I don't exactly understand which encoding it uses for the byte code. I assumed it uses the encoding of the file I safe my script, but I want to make it independent of the encoding of the script. Can someone help me here please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to get. use UTF-8 (which all web understand, and so there is not problems using accented characters, nor to learn that 196 mean something. Unicode is the "independent" (it is designed to support nearly all encoding). or use HTML entities. But your page will have an encoding. Input from user also. Try to stick to one (to remove missencoding).

Comment: It is really unclear what actual _problem_ you are trying to solve here, so please start with a proper explanation of that.

Comment: The value 196 (or 0xC4) has no specific encoding, it's only a number value... however, _using_ an encoding to _translate_ the number into a _glyph_ will have different results, depending on the encoding used...  chr() ignores the encoding (documented behaviour)